# What's the deal with catching exceptions?

Tags: ios, exception

So I've read a lot about catching exceptions.  Let's talk about this and iOS together.  I've used it with Google Analytics to submit information about the crash and using that to fix bugs.

But this raises a question.  Can catching these exceptions help prevent apps from crashing.  Can you theoretically prevent that bit of code from crashing the app and keep the app open.  Now I get the fact that it would probably be impossible to do if there was no memory to be used but it would still be nice to know about.

Sorry if this sounds like a stupid questions and I really should read more about it and do some more research.  Any information would be helpful.

I do have a fairly decent knowledge of iOS obj-c for my age and am willing to look into what you have to say.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, I'm also a pretty young programmer. Would love to talk to you if you're interested. Various contact info is on my profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions on iOS should never be caught; they are fatal for a reason.  Unlike most languages that have a rich exception hierarchy and multiple means of throwing/catching exceptions for the benefit of the program as a whole, Cocoa-Touch code is built around the principle that all exceptions are fatal.  It is a mistake to think that you can catch an exception thrown through any frames of Apple-provided code and have your process continue unhindered.  It is an even more grave mistake to catch and rethrow the exception for the purpose of logging.

The exceptions thrown by Cocoa-Touch indicate serious errors in program logic, or undefined and unresolvable state in an object.  It is not OK to ignore them, or log them after catching them.  They must be fixed and prevented from being thrown in the first place in order to truly guarantee your process remains stable.